# Garmin Edge 500 Compatible Parts

Tags: bike-computer, garmin

My Garmin Edge 500 is having some trouble with the buttons on the right hand side.

After many years of faithful service the start/stop button barely functions and it looks like the external rubber has worn through. The reset/lap button isn't doing much better. Battery life is still excellent though!

Edge 500 back cases seem a bit difficult to come by but I've heard the Edge 200 used the same shell.

Is there a good way I can get an edge 500 compatible back case that I might not know about? Are there compatible replacement cases from other models?

Answer (score 1):

I found this link on eBay for $31 USD with shipping added.

[Garmin Edge 500 Back cover-case](https://www.ebay.com/itm/264315610631)

The title of the listing is "Garmin Edge 500 Back Cover Edge 500 Back Case Replacement Part Blue & White."

Before you put down money on a case, ensure that the button function is still working and that just the case is failing.  It would be a shame to spend money if the button was also on its way out.  Mechanical switches can wear out.  Good luck.

Comment: looking at the listing, they are selling them used, not new.  Ito looks like you would need to solder in the speaker connection based on the pictures given.  The rest of it looks to be replace with the guts from your 500 (sans speaker).

Comment: Three other options: 1) find someone who is selling their old Edge 500 because they are upgrading.  You may be able to get a great deal on a complete 500 this way.  The 500 is getting pretty old, generation-wise.  2) Consider moving to the current one, an Edge 530.  Garmin has made many improvements (500 --> 510 --> 520 --> 520 plus --> 530).  3) If you like the smaller form factor of the 500 over the larger 530, then check out the Garmin Edge 130.  It has the most important features of the 530 but cheaper.  Replacing the case on your 500 should be cheaper, but know that there are options.